# Using a HTML Mail template with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter email class to send emails when the user register to my website or perform some activity inside my website.

The thing is that, with this simple code below I can only send very simple HTML emails. And also I will have to pass the entire HTML message to the function. Is there any way so that I could load the entire template in the function itself and just pass a message which is to be placed inside the template as we do in codeigniter with views.

```
$message = 'Thank you for your order \n';
$message .= 'We will contact you soon';
$this->email($message);

public function email($message = NULL){
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->mailtype('html');
    $this->email->from('abbbba@gmail.com', 'Sohan Kc');
    $this->email->to('abbbbaa@gmail.com'); 

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message($message);    

    $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: I recommend making a wrapper around the mail function, this way you can update your codeigniter mailer without issues and stay up to date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do as you already stated? :)
The email classes message method requires a string to be passed. Just load a View and pass the returned string to the method.

```
public function email($message = NULL){
    $this->load->library('email');

    $mydata = array('message' => 'I am a message that will be passed to a view');
    $message = $this->load->view('my_email_template', $mydata, true);        

    $this->email->mailtype('html');
    $this->email->from('sohanmax2@gmail.com', 'Sohan Kc');
    $this->email->to('sohanmax02@gmail.com'); 

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message($message);    

    $this->email->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I send emails but got the html code as body, I had to add the headers to get correct content like below and it will works out.

$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');

$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');